# How to export all singleband raster pixel values into excel or .csv in ArcGIS Pro?

Tags: arcgis-pro

I have NDVI rasters and I would like to export ALL pixel values into an Excel compatible format.  I would ideally like to have a column for pixel values and another column for frequency.

Comment: Have you classified your NDVI? If it's still in its *as calculated* state each value is extremely likely to have a frequency of 1. Do you have any python ability? arcpy would help a lot but it's still doable if you can classify your raster to integer values.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't know any python yet.  The point you raise regarding frequency is very important.  In fact, I was just waiting to submit another post regarding reducing the significant figs of the data.  I think that I will multiply my rasters by 100 or 1000 and then reclassify to integer values.  I'll still need to figure out how to export the classes into excel.

Comment: You're right there, the integer of the raster multiplied by 100 (or 1000) would work nicely, from there build a raster attribute table (RAT) https://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//0017000000m2000000 which is a dbf file with the same name as the raster, this file will have precisely what you're after. Excel opens DBase IV files *but don't save it as a dbf* from Excel.